# Constructors in superclass and subclass

Tags: java

I have piece of code below

```
public class Super {

    public  Super (){
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "I am Super";
    }
}


public class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub() {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "I am SubClass";
    }
}


public class test {

    public static void main (String [] args){
         Sub ss = new Sub();

    }
}
```

//RESULT

I am SubClass

I am SubClass

As per theory it should call super class constructor before and then subclass.
But when i execute it, it always print subclass constrctor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it will call the `super` class constructor first, the `toString()` method that will be invoked is the run time type's implementation (if it has one). Since the object being created is of type `Sub`, `Sub`'s implementation of `toString()` will be invoked. This is the basis of polymorphism.

Comment: Isn't that there should be only one `public` class in a file? Or have I mistaken?

Comment: @Aniruddha Yes, but we can safely assume they posted their code like this for simplicity.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I tried to over ride the super class toString method it like this



`public class Super extends Object {

 public Super() {

  System.out.println(this.toString());

 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "I am Super";
 }
}`

Is this correct use of @Override??
this doesnt work anyway

Comment: how can i override toString method of Superclass??

Comment: I meant to say how can i get output like below

I am Super

I am SubClass

Comment: @nomad Have the sub class `toString()` invoke the super implementation with `super.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is an instance of subClass (which contains super class as well). So, toString() of Subclass will be called for - `System.out.println(this.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ss = new Sub();
```

Object instance created is Sub, hence the toString() will be called of subclass

Even if you use

```
Super ss = new Sub();
```

The result will be same

Only if you use

```
Super ss = new Super();
```

you will get output as

```
I am Super
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there should be only one `public` class in a file? Or have I mistaken?

Anyways even if you do

```
Super ss = new Sub();
```

output will be

```
I am SubClass
I am SubClass
```

But if you do `Super ss = new Super();`, the output will be

```
I am Super
```

Comment: You are correct about the one `public class` per file. They probably just posted all the code together for simplicity.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you :). Just wanted to clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that theoretically it should print Super Class Constructor data first and then Sub Class constructor data. But Once you create Subclass object, this object will be used while executing your constructor code both for Super Class as well as Sub Class.

Sub ss = new Sub();

Will call Default Super() method of Java and Pass Sub Class Object to it and This Sub Class object will call its **toString()** method and that is why it is printing both the times 'I am SubClass'.

Just try using some string argument in your Super Class constructor and you will see it printing.

I am SuperClass
I am SubClass

Answer (score 0):

In 'Super' class constructor, print another string("I am Parent"), instead of calling this.toString() which will always invoke the overridded method of toString() in 'Sub' class because 'this' corresponds to that new Object of 'Sub' class created in main method.

In this case you will get output as,

I am Parent

I am Child